Are halides or gem-dihalides more susceptible to nucleophillic substitution?
Is 1-bromo-1-iodocyclohexane ($\ce{C6H10BrI}$) really more susceptible to $\mathrm{S_N1}$ than 2-chloropropane ($\ce{CH3-CHCl-CH3}$)? I can't exactly understand why.
According to my understanding, $\ce{CH3CH^+CH3}$ forms a more stable carbocation than $\ce{C5H10C^+Br}$ since bromine is electronegative and its electron pulling power is greater than its tendency to donate electrons.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135012/stability-of-%ce%b1-chlorocarbocations

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40076/stability-of-carbocations-cf3-vs-ch3
